# Router Zyxel EX3301-T0 firewall, rule priority

Tags: networking, router, firewall

Could you say anything about how the router Zyxel EX3301-T0 works with respect to its firewall functionality? I have a specific question:
If you set up Security > Firewall > General, level to "High", and create
an Access Control Rule that drops FTP traffic from LAN to WAN; what happens?

-- Will the text "Only local network traffic and LAN to WAN service
(Telnet, FTP, HTTP, HTTPS, DNS, POP3, SMTP) is permitted" have priority? Or ACL?

I e will FTP be dropped?

I couldn't find the answer in Zyxel's manual (470 pages), about which rule that has priority.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.